# Undefined variable: arr in /... on line 332 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the following error in wordpress site. Any idea what we are doing wrong? This started when we upgraded to WP 4.1.5

Notice: Undefined variable: arr in /custom_helpers.php on line 332 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /custom_helpers.php on line 332 Notice: Undefined variable: arr in /custom_helpers.php on line 332 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /custom_helpers.php on line 332 Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /custom_helpers.php on line 339 Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /custom_helpers.php on line 345

This is line 332

```
function filter_pr_review( $field, $content ) {
if( empty($content) ) 
{
    if($field == 'lens_shift') return 'No';
    return false;
}

if( is_array( $content ) )
{
    return $content->name;
}
else
{

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if( $key === $field )
        {
            return $content->name;
        }
    }

    if ($content == 0) 
    {
        return $content;
        //return $content->name;
        //return '0';
    }

   elseif($content == 1)
    {
        //return '1';
        //return $value;
        return $content->name;
        //return $content[1];
    }
```

This is the code that generates the table

```
$specs = array(
'model_number'        => 'Projector Model',
'technology'          => 'Technology',
'price'               => 'Price',
'brightness'          => 'Brightness (Manufacturer Claim)',
'contrast'            => 'Contrast Ratio',
'native_resolution'   => 'Native Resolution',
'max_resolution'      => 'Max Resolution',
'3d'                  => '3D',
'aspect_ratio'        => 'Native Aspect Ratio',
'video_compatibility' => 'Video Compatibility',
'hdtv'                => 'HDTV',
'lamp_life'           => 'Lamp Life',
'noise_level'         => 'Noise Level (-db)',
'audio'               => 'Audio',
'hdmi_dvi'            => 'DVI or HDMI',
'power_zoom/focus'    => 'Power Zoom/Focus',
'lens_shift'          => 'Optional Lens Shift',
'zoom_lens_ratio'     => 'Zoom Lens Ratio',
'lens_shift'          => 'Lens Shift',
'optional_lenses'     => 'Optional Lens',
'classroom'           => 'Classroom',
'wireless_networking' => 'Wireless Networking',
'dimensions'          => 'Dimensions',
'weight'              => 'Weight',
'warranty'            => 'Warranty'
);

<table id="specs-full" class="specs-table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sec-header" colspan="2"><?php echo $manufacturer . " " . get_field('model_number', $post->post_parent) ?> Specs</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    foreach ( $specs as $spec => $title )
    {
        $field  = get_field( $spec, $post->post_parent );
        $output = filter_pr_review( $spec, get_field($spec, $post->ID) );
        $override =     array('3d','aspect_ratio','video_compatibility','hdtv','lamp_life','noise_level','audio','hdmi_dvi','power_zoom/focus','lens_shift','zoom_lens_ratio','lens_shift','optional_lenses','classroom','wireless_networking','dimensions','weight','warranty');
        if(in_array($spec, $override))
        {
            if($output == '' || $output == '-') $output = 'No';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="title">' . $title . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $output . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: When is the variable $arr first used in this script?

Comment: function filter_pr_review( $field, $content ) {
 if( empty($content) ) 
 {
  if($field == 'lens_shift') return 'No';
  return false;
 }

 if( is_array( $content ) )
 {
  return $content->name;
 }
 else
 {

Comment: I do not see $arr there.

Comment: i placed all code that calls the filter_pr_review function in the main message above.